# Telerik Report With WPF

Tags: asp.net

I used Telerik Report control with WPF(C#). I assinged data to Telerik Report but i don't want to open report but i need to print directly when it filled.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `PrintReport method`

```
    function MyPrint()
    {
        <%=ReportViewer1.ClientID %>.PrintReport();
    }
```